# Implementing DefaultContractResolver to include certain properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, serialization, json.net

I have implemented DefaultContractResolver to include certain properties that i want to serialize. I can extract out each property and Object.property (nested objects) using the following code, however, on trying to serialize it doesn't find the property.property for nested objects and fails on conversion.

```
public class DynamicContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private List<string> mPropertiesToSerialize = null;

    public DynamicContractResolver(List<string> propertiesToSerialize)
    {
        this.mPropertiesToSerialize = propertiesToSerialize;
    }

    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        IList<JsonProperty> objProperties = new List<JsonProperty>();
        IList<JsonProperty> properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);

        objProperties = properties.Where(p => mPropertiesToSerialize.Contains(p.PropertyName)).ToList();

        foreach (var jProperty in properties)
        {
            if (!jProperty.PropertyType.IsClass) 
                continue;

            var nestedObjProperties = base.CreateProperties(jProperty.PropertyType, memberSerialization);
            foreach (var nestedjProperty in nestedObjProperties)
            {
                if (objProperties.Any(nj => (nj.PropertyName == nestedjProperty.PropertyName)))
                    continue;

                if (mPropertiesToSerialize.Contains(nestedjProperty.PropertyName))
                {
                    objProperties.Add(nestedjProperty);
                }
            }
        }
        return objProperties;
    }
}
```

Usage where this fails:

```
var contractResolver = new DynamicContractResolver(propertiesToSerialize);          
var serializedObj =
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contact, Formatting.None,
                new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = contractResolver });
```

Using above, i can have it iterate all properties of Contact object, but on serialization, it doesn't seem to drill down in to embedded objects like Account here and throws error that property was not found. Since i am using list of JsonProperty, i was hoping that the objects i add to list to be serialized have enough information for serialize to extract appropriate properties from nested objects. Obviously this goes only 1 level deep, but that is not the issue at hand.

Why wouldn't it drill down in to nested object and extract it's property value from Contact?

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public Account Account { get; set; }
}
public class Account 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What are you passing to `propertiesToSerialize`?

Comment: List of Property names. In the example, it would be something like: 

    Case #1

    Name
    Account.Id
    Account.EmailAddress

    Case #2

    Name
    Id
    EmailAddress


I have tried passing in properties both ways as list and it never pulls Id and EmailAddress to serialize.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way around this issue.

Instead of overriding createProperties, i ended up setting property.ShouldSerialize to false for every property by overriding CreateProperty (JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)) that was not needed and got back just the ones that were needed!